# Status of System.Json in .Net 4.5

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

MSDN talks about a [System.Json namespace in .Net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.aspx) (although it says 'preview only').

I can't find it anywhere in 4.5 though, it's not in System.Runtime.Serialization as mentioned on MSDN - was it removed from the release?

The doc appears to match a package that's on Nuget, but it's labeled beta and you can only find it by specifying the version on the commandline (`Install-Package System.Json -Version 4.0.20126.16343`).

Will these classes make it into the framework/will they be supported?

I know about other json libaries on .net but I'd prefer to have one in the framework (/in the future).

Comment: Yes, it's "preview only" on MSDN and beta in NuGet - basically it's not fully released yet. You can install it from in VS as well, if you tick "Show preview releases" or something similar (I can't see the UI right now). I'm not sure what's confusing here - it's a preview, so nothing's guaranteed. It's reasonable to suppose it may very well be in a future version of .NET, but I don't think anyone's guaranteeing that...

Comment: I find it confusing that the MSDN page hasn't been updated - 4.5 has been released 6 months ago.

Comment: Well the last release of the System.Json package was in February 2012...

Comment: Yest but MSDN doesn't mention the package - it says it should be in System.Runtime.Serialization... I have nothing against Nuget, I just wasn't sure if I was using the right stuff.

Comment: Ah, I see. I suspect at one point there was the *possibility* of it being included in .NET 4.5, but that it didn't make the cut.

Comment: Still not available in 4.5.2. Sad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, since I was quite comfortable with the System.Json API, I took the port from Mono, fixed some bugs and put it on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hjson/):

Creating a JsonObject is a simple as

```
new JsonObject
{
  { "foo", 1 },
  { "bar", ";)" },
};
```

The package also includes Hjson but you can ignore the Hjson types if you don't need them.